# Member not found (exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND using Visual Studio2019 Community

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, msbi

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for learning the SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS). During the practice session I got an issue.

> member not found (exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND” Visual Studio2019 Community

Report--->Add--->New item

[image: The Option that I Chose]

Issue

[image: Issue in Adding new item in the report]

Comment: Did you speak to your tutor? What type of item are you trying to add here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug.

I (and others) reported it to Microsoft last year. Last week it's status was changed to "Fixed - pending Release".

I expect the new version will be released in the next week or so.

You can see the issue here

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-create-new-report/1266633?from=email

The "Add New Report" wizard still works.

The workaround is to ..

- add an existing item or create a dummy report using the wizard
- Empty this report so you have a blank report
- Make copies of this report in the solution explorer (just select it and do Ctrl+C then Ctrl-V)
- Build your report as normal and save.

Comment: If you follow the issue (... top right of the first post) you will be notified when the fix is released